# Import Data from XLSX

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I'm trying to import data from an Excel file into Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Express Edition (64-bit) using the following query

```
USE DB1;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

SELECT * INTO ContractHeader
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=D:\Users\User1\Downloads\Book1.xlsx', [Sheet1$]);
GO
```

However, when I run it, I'm getting the following error plus I then also need to start the SQL Service manually.

> Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run
> the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
> Configuration option 'Ad Hoc
> Distributed Queries' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE
> statement to install.
>
> Msg 109, Level 20, State 0, Line 8   > A
> transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
> server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has
> been ended.)

Comment: Via SSMS, in Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers > Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 do you have the "Allow inprocess" option ticked? Have you tried to untick it?

Comment: It was enabled. After I disabled it and run the above query I received the following error: Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Good, so now we get to see the real errors... Is the file open in another process? (i.e.: do you have it open in Excel?) Does the account under which SQL Server Express executes have file system ACLs that permit it access to your `D:\Users\User1\Downloads` folder?

Comment: I've just created a new folder C:\Test\Book1.xlsx. I'm pretty sure SQL has access to it but when I run the query this is what I get: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7311, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_TABLES_INFO" for OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)". The provider supports the interface, but returns a failure code when it is used.

Comment: When you installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable did you use `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` or `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe`? SQL Server is a 64 bit process and needs 64 bit drivers to access other data sources.